# Linux command when executing a file &>

Tags: linux, bash

I have some problems with understanding a command when executing a program.Let's say that I have this command

```
./program "input/file" &> "output/file"
```

As I know this should read from the input file...but how...I can't understand... I know that you can do it with redirecting like

```
./program <"input/file" >"output/file"
```

but how can I read the input file with the first form?.

Comment: Have your program interpret `argv`, and `fopen` a file.

Comment: `program` only reads from `input/file` if that is what `program` is written to do. You are simply providing a file name as an argument; what that argument is used for depends on the implementation of `program`.

Comment: Are you asking how to write `program` in such a way as to open a file given on its argument list? If so, we'd need to know what language you're using.

Answer (score 2):

If you want call your script `./program "input/file" &> "output/file"` you should pass file path and file name like argument
In your script it will look like this

`$1` - is first argument passed to script. In this case it is "input/file"

```
while read line
    do
    echo -e "$line \n"
    #do something
done < $1
```

And one more thing there is difference between redirection '&>' and '>'

`>` - redirect stdout to file

`&>` - redirect both stdout and stderr to file